# Run certain callback on authentication failure with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, callback, customization

I'm trying to implement this scenario:

> When a user fails to authenticate, I'll show him a big sour face.

How can I do that with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)?
I have a dirty solution like finding the error message inside the `<% flash %>` which is really really bad. Is there a better way? Something like setting a variable inside some controller, etc.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a custom_failure.rb in your lib directory, with:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    your_path
  end

  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

2.In you Devise initializer, include:

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
end
```

3.Make sure Rails is loadin your lib files, in your application.rb :

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

And then restart your server.

Comment: This will create a redirect and completely bypass the sessions/new.html.erb, won't it? I saw this answer in SO already, but I'm actually asking how can I override some controoler, such that I could pass to the sessions/new.html.erb some @variable.

Comment: same here; would be great to be able to handle the failure